# cannot share streaming videos using Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent, video-streaming

I am trying to share youtube videos using code that looks like

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("video/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PW_88sL_2dA"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Video"));
```

but this not getting shared in any of the app. What is the wrong I am doing here ?

Comment: Are there any apps on your phone that declares an `Intent-filter` with  `android:mimeType="video/*` ? Try using something like `video/mp4`.

Comment: BTW. This URL isn't a link to video. It's a link to a web page (which includes a videp). Application on other end of your sharing will just a video.

Comment: where to share? are you trying to stream or something else?

Comment: Do you want to share the video file or just the url?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because the URL you are using points to a webpage rather than a video. Use this instead "http://www.youtube.com/embed/PW_88sL_2dA?feature=oembed" and tell me if it works.

Comment: Ankit Rawat the link you provided works fine.I have seen share link button in Youtube app in my android device.that is the reason i was trying to do the same.

Comment: yes i couldn't replicate what youtube app is doing to share its video.This there any other alternative solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no way to share youtube video  to any other application ,

you can only share some contain file  to other application .

> youtube is not allow to share that video  because its similar to
>   download video from youtube which highly illegal.
>   Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer came very late, but I was searching to solve the same problem.
how to share Youtube link with Facebook?

the answer that works for me is to add the video link in the Intent.EXTRA_TEXT
and set the type to "text/plain".

```
public static void startShareActionActivity(Context context,String subject,String text,String videoUrl)
{
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, videoUrl);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, text);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Select your favourite network"));
}
```